# What could cause a 13 year old diabetic American Eskimo to vomit about an hour after she eats?

Tags: dogs, health, feeding

I'm pet-sitting my father's 13-year-old American Eskimo for a week.

The dog is diabetic and has been for a number of years after contracting erlichiosis and Lyme disease years ago.

My father mentioned that she was not feeling great a few days before he left her with me, but that she seemed to be better as of the day before he dropped her off with me.

But in the first few days of her being here, she's vomiting within about an hour after she eats. She doesn't eat a lot, but around getting her insulin shots, she has her rituals that my father has created, which involve various sequences of "treats". For example, we have to put two small pieces of "Snaw-somes" beef and cheese on the floor. She will sniff them, then roll over for her shot in the morning. In the evening, repeat, but after the shot, she gets two of my father's home-made liver treats: liver, corn-meal, egg, and I don't know what else, baked in the oven. Now she runs the show. If you don't follow these and other rituals, she will pester you and bark until she gets what she knows she is supposed to get, which drives me crazy!

Her food is a dry kibble (not sure what brand, but I'm guessing some form of Beneful with orange, red, and green kibble). But we will give her some table food such as cut up left over meat, but not a lot of fat at all.

Aside from all said above, she seems to be behaving normally, is alert, likes to go for rides in the car. No apparent signs of distress or pain, or abnormal behavior.

---

**Update**: she seems to be doing a bit better. Eliminated giving her some of those Snawsome treats and changed her diet over to mostly real food with some rice. Wondering if it's those nasty treats that are soft and maybe contain something that bothers her stomach.

One day I saw her outside fishing around the yard for long grass and she ate a bunch and then made her self throw it up. Since then, she has been doing relatively well.

I'm also wondering if her insulin needs to be adjusted.

Comment: When was the last time you checked her blood sugar?

Comment: Related question [Can I use a human glucose meter be used to check the blood sugar of a pet?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6119)

Answer (score 2):

If the treat that you're giving her is not her normal treat (sounds like it isn't, since your dad gives homemade treats), it could be that she's allergic to something in it.

The fact that she went and ate grass to vomit tells me that it was something that she ate that irritated her stomach. Some dogs' stomachs are just more sensitive to that sort of thing (whether they have diabetes or not). My Silky is one of them and this has happened with him.

Normally, I'd suggest having the dog fast after its been vomiting because that helps its stomach to settle, but I don't know how wise that would be for a diabetic dog. I would just eliminate the non-homemade treats because that seems to be the likely culprit.

Answer (score -2):

If her food - or the amount she consumes - is changed in any way, surely her insulin must be adjusted, clever question! Call her vet for advise!

Comment: That can be a challenge especially when one day she seems eat a reasonable amount and then the next day doesn't seem to want to eat much at all. I need a devices that measures the amount and type of food to determine the proper amount of insulin, which is given twice a day. Heads up to any inventors out there. ;-)

Comment: Could you expand on this at all? I get that you're giving an answer, but with a single sentence it seems more like a comment.