# Can a human glucose meter be used to check the blood sugar of a pet?

Tags: health, diseases

Diabetes is a terrible disease that affects people and pets. If both I, and my pet, have diabetes, can I use my meter to check my pets blood sugar?  On a quick check of the internet, I found a [commercial reference](http://www.alphatrakmeter.com/alphatrak2-species-specific.html) suggesting that I need to purchase a special meter for a cat or a dog.  Is this just commercial hype, or do I really need a species specific meter?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No you don't need a species specific meter; you can use a human meter for this purpose, but regular engagement with a vet, and having a discussion with a vet on this, is very important.

In any event, I got curious about your question and so did a little research on feline diabetes. This led me to a nicely [written article](http://www.vet.cornell.edu/FHC/health_resources/brochure_diabetes.cfm) from the Veterinary school at Cornell. Importantly, there was a link to a very [thorough article](http://www.sugarcats.net/sites/harry/bgtest.htm) on blood glucose testing at home with a solid discussion on how to pick a meter, etc.

Given that a vet school linked me there, I'll take that as a good sign and suggest that the commercial reference is hype.

Comment: Thanks great answer and supporting links. This answer is supported by our exotics vet.  At exotics clinic last night, while he was checking a ferrets sugar, I asked and he said he was using a human meter.  He started to tell me what the only difference was, but got side tracked.